# In c# .net, how do I create an actionlink containing both the fragment (anchortag) while giving it a custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a navbar in C# .Net using bootstrap and using Actionlinks.
I am implementing javascript that uses easyscroll to access the different sections. Two of my 3 links in the navbar are sections on the frontpage, while the second is a link to a second page. 
I got the scrolling to work now, but using the actionlink overload (see below) doesnt seem to allow me to specify a class name as well.

**this works, but does not implement the class i want.**

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.Title, "Index", "Home", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "about", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: null)
```

**I tried the following:**

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.Title, "Index", "Home", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "about", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: null, new { @class = "navbar-brand"})
```

This gives the following error:  **Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified**

**I cant seem to figure it out - I thought i could add this argument, as long as it was last?**
**This would work:**

`@Html.ActionLink("ButtonText", "Action","Controller", new {@class="btn btn-default"})`

I hope you can help me out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is self-explanatory...

But just in case, you want to set the `htmlAttributes` parameter, so instead of:

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.Title, "Index", "Home", 
                         ... 
                       , htmlAttributes: null, new { @class = "navbar-brand"})
```

Where you are setting `htmlAttributes` to `null`, *and then* trying to set up a non-named parameter... set the actual parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.Title, "Index", "Home", 
                         ... 
                       , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "navbar-brand"})
```

Comment: That is indeed self explanatory now that you mention it. I even thought i had tried that, apparently not in the correct way.

Thank you!

Comment: That's what we're here for! :-)